# Flutter desktop questions

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-windows

Please, if I setup flutter desktop on my Mac, can I develop a desktop application for windows?… (using mac for developing a windows desktop app)

Thank you .

I tried developing flutter desktop app with my Mac for macos .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the code on any OS. However in order to compile your code you will have to do it on Windows OS.

See the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/desktop):

> Note: To compile a desktop application, you must build it on the targeted platform: build a Windows application on Windows, a macOS application on macOS, and a Linux application on Linux.